# Python - TicTacToe Error

Tags: python

So this is my tic tac toe python game, but the result is that after someone wins, you have to choose another square before it ends, and when it ends, it never shows 'player one won!' or 'player two won!' I'm not sure why that is happening. Can someone please help?

```
# Tic Tac Toe Game
import time
import sys
who = 'p1'
finished = 'no'
board = [0,1,2,
         3,4,5,
         6,7,8]

def show():
    print (board[0], '|', board [1], '|', board[2])
    print ('---------')
    print (board[3], '|', board [4], '|', board[5])
    print ('---------')
    print (board[6], '|', board [7], '|', board[8])

def checkWin():
    if board[0] == 'x' and board[3] == 'x' and board[6] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'y' and board[3] == 'y' and board[6] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[1] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[7] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[1] == 'y' and board[4] == 'y' and board[7] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[2] == 'y' and board[5] == 'y' and board[8] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[2] == 'x' and board[5] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'y' and board[1] == 'y' and board[2] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'x' and board[1] == 'x' and board[2] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[3] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[5] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[3] == 'y' and board[4] == 'y' and board[5] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[6] == 'y' and board[7] == 'y' and board[8] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[6] == 'x' and board[7] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'y' and board[4] == 'y' and board[8] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[2] == 'y' and board[4] == 'y' and board[6] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[2] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[6] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    else:
        return False

print ('Welcome to a two-player Tic.Tac.Toe Game!')
time.sleep(2)
print ("Just pick a spot to put your mark!")
time.sleep(1.5)
print ('Now, start!')
time.sleep(0.2)
print (show())

while checkWin() == False:
    while who == 'p1':
        try:
            p1 = int(input('Player 1, select a spot: '))

            if board[p1] != 'x' and board[p1] != 'o':
                board[p1] = 'x'
                who = 'p2'
                break

            else:
                print ('This spot is taken.')
                pass

        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print ('That is not available. Please try again.')

    print (show())
    while who == 'p2':
        try:
            p2 = int(input('Player 2, select a spot: '))

            if board[p2] != 'x' and board[p2] != 'o':
                board[p2] = 'o'
                who = 'p1'
                break

            else:
                print ('This spot is taken.')
                pass

        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print ('That is not available. Please try again.')

    print (show())
while checkWin == True:
    # x
    if board[0] == 'x' and board[3] == 'x' and board[6] == 'x':
        print ('Player 1 won!')
        sys.exit()
    elif board[1] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[7] == 'x':
        print ('Player 1 won!')
        sys.exit()
    elif board[2] == 'x' and board[5] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
        print ('Player 1 won!')
        sys.exit()
    elif board[0] == 'x' and board[1] == 'x' and board[2] == 'x':
        print ('Player 1 won!')
        sys.exit()
    elif board[3] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[5] == 'x':
        print ('Player 1 won!')
        sys.exit()
    elif board[6] == 'x' and board[7] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
        print ('Player 1 won!')
        sys.exit()
    elif board[0] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
        print ('Player 1 won!')
        sys.exit()
    elif board[2] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[6] == 'x':
        print ('Player 1 won!')
        sys.exit()
    # y
    else:
        print ('Player 2 won!')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Try printing something after `checkWin==True.`

Comment: `while checkWin == True:`  --> `while checkWin() == True:`

Comment: `while checkWin() == True:` is unnecessary because by the time the code reaches this point `checkWin()` is True (this is after a `while checkWin() ==False`) so you can just have your `if...elif...else`

Comment: It would be more useful if `checkWin` would return the number of the player that won. Then you don't have to repeat all those checks to know who did.

Comment: You can get rid of all those `if/elif` chains by creating a list of tuples with the winning sequences: `[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9), ...]`, and then looping through them.